# Two controllers, two calls of same factory for same http request and synchronous conflics

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, controllers, angular-services, angular-http

I have one mainCtrl that I inject in  tag of my index.html like :

```
<html ng-app="app" lang="fr" ng-controller="mainCtrl" xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org">
```

So, when I display any template (page), the index.html is called so the mainCtrl too.

For each view called, I attach in the $routeProvider a specific controller like this :

```
.when("/factures",
{
    controller: "facturesCtrl",
    templateUrl: "assets/partials/factures.tpl.html",
    resolve: {
        checkPermission: function(Auth){
            return Auth.getUser();
        }
    }
})
```

---

In my case the dataUsers function call a factory with several parameters who determines which URL (from api) I'll call, so the parameters depends of the function. Example.

**mainCtrl :**

```
$scope.dataUsers = function()
{
    $rootScope.PARAMS.a = 'all';

    User.get($rootScope.PARAMS, 'client', '').then(function(dataUsers)
    {
        //...

    }, function(reason){

        // ...
    }
}
```

**user.fct.js**

```
function getUserData($rootScope, $q, $http, $timeout, loadData)
{
    return {
        get: function(user, type, responseType)
        {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            loadData.post('POST', $rootScope.directory + 'api/'+ type, user, responseType, function(data){

                if(data.status == 'ok')
                {
                    $timeout(function(){

                        deferred.resolve(data);
                    }, 250);
                }
            }); 

            return deferred.promise;                    
        }
    }
}
```

---

In some case I call the same factory but with a different parameters. For example the bill's controller call the http.get factory (above) too for displaying a last bill of customer.

**facturesCtrl**

```
$scope.dataFactures = function()
{
    $rootScope.PARAMS.a = 'last';

    User.get($rootScope.PARAMS, 'facture', '').then(function(dataFactures)
    {
        //...

    }, function(reason){

        //...
    }); 
}

$scope.dataFactures();
```

---

**Now my problem :**

Both of controllers : **mainCtrl** and **FacturesCtrl** are called in the same time when my root is /factures.

So, the same factory is called twice but the parameters are false. For example Angular JS seems to call the differentes methods with this order :

```
1) dataUsers()                      -> rooscope.action = "all"
2) dataFactures()                   -> rooscope.action = "last"
3) get.getUserData(params, 'string')-> params = "all", 'string' = '/client'
3) get.getUserData(params, 'string')-> params = "last", 'string' = '/factures'

should be :

1) dataUsers()                      -> rooscope.action = "all"
2) get.getUserData(params, 'string')-> params = "all", 'string' = '/client'
2) dataFactures()                   -> rooscope.action = "last"
3) get.getUserData(params, 'string') -> params = "last", 'string' = '/factures'
```

Because, the parameters are mixed, by this way the API return error !

---

**I tried :**

To call the dataUsers function when the callback promise is launched:

**mainCtrl :**

```
$scope.dataUsers = function()
{
    $rootScope.PARAMS.a = 'all';

    User.get($rootScope.PARAMS, 'client', '').then(function(dataUsers) //...

    //..
}
```

**facturesCtrl :**

```
   $scope.dataFactures = function()
    {
        $rootScope.PARAMS.a = 'last';

        User.get($rootScope.PARAMS, 'facture', '').then(function(dataFactures)
        {   
            // DATA USERS START
            $scope.dataUsers(); 

        }, function(reason){

            //...
        }); 
    }    
    $scope.dataFactures();
```

This working fine but I'm not fan of this method because :

1. I can only make synchronous calls, and I prefer split independantly
   each calls (asynchrone).
2. With this method, I can partially
       controlling my calls. For example I can't call first dataUsers(),
       wait the promise callback and call dataFactures().
3. Because, the dataUsers() have to be call for all views, by my method, I
   must declare a controller by view. I think is too bad to
   declare a controller for a page like "termes of uses", "infos", "hot
   news" or others sub views which displays only text..

---

I hope I was clear enough , in other words I don't know if my way to configure the application is good...

Thank you in advance for your clarification :)

Comment: Let's see if I understand what you are trying to do: 1- About the controll of your calls: do you need to have a specifc order for the functions to be called? Do you ALWAYS want to call $scope.dataFactures first and then $scope.dataUsers()?  2- If the  dataUsers() function needs to be called from many different views, just define it once on the mainCtrl  and pass different parameters like dataUsers(someParameters).

Comment: `ng-controller="mainCtrl"` of course causes mainCtrl to always get called.

Comment: @dluz No I don't want order. Just call dataUsers() and dataFactures() in same time. If I moved the $scope.dataUsers() in dataFactures() it's because I haven't been able to call the same factorie twice (synchronous - dataUsers and dataFactures) because the parameters found themselves mixed...

Comment: @KévinVilelaPinto It seems both dataUsers() and dataFactures() should receive an "action" parameters like so: dataUsers('all') and dataFactures('last') this way things don't get mixed up, have you tried that? To rely on the value of the $rootScope.action is not a good idea - also remeber that $rootScope is a global variable it should be used in only few scenarios.

Comment: @dluz, the all param must be an object with others properties like, token, idClient, ...  `$rootScope.PARAMS   = {};
$rootScope.PARAMS.t = $localStorage.userToken;
$rootScope.PARAMS.c = $localStorage.userLogin;` 
$rootScope.PARAMS.a = 'all';

Comment: @dluz and this object change compared with called functions